# How to rotate the camera on the same axis

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

Beginner to threejs,
I'm trying to build a car using 3d model, where I'm trying to switch camera view from outside the car and from the driver seat.

When the camera is outside I would like rotate the car and see its view. But when I switch to the driver seat view then I don't want the car to rotate instead I want only the camera to rotate from its fixed position. But as of now the camera moves outside the car.

How to achieve this scenario? I tried to reach this below is the code that I used.

```
    <Canvas dpr={[1, 2]}>
     <color attach="background" args={["#101010"]} />
      <Suspense fallback={<></>}>
        <OrbitControls
          enablePan={true}
          enableZoom={true}
          panSpeed={0.1}
          enableRotate={true}
          rotateSpeed={0.5}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2.1}
          maxDistance={20}
        />

        <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[0, 3, 15]} ref={cameraRef} />
 
        <Stage environment={null} intensity={0.6} castShadow={false}>
          <Car {...props} />
        </Stage>
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with separate cameras and/or separate OC, and switching by buttons for example

```
  const outsideCamera = useRef();
  const driverSeatCamera = useRef();
  const outsideControls = useRef();
  const driverSeatControls = useRef();
  const activeCamera = useRef(outsideCamera);
  const activeControls = useRef(outsideControls);

  useFrame(() => {
    activeControls.current.update();
  });

  const switchToOutsideView = () => {
    activeCamera.current = outsideCamera;
    activeControls.current = outsideControls;
  };

  const switchToDriverSeatView = () => {
    activeCamera.current = driverSeatCamera;
    activeControls.current = driverSeatControls;
  };

   <PerspectiveCamera ref={outsideCamera} makeDefault position={[0, 3, 15]} />
   <OrbitControls ref={outsideControls} enablePan={true} enableZoom={true} />
   <PerspectiveCamera ref={driverSeatCamera} position={[0, 1, 0]} />
   <OrbitControls ref={driverSeatControls} enablePan={true} enableZoom={true} />

   <button onClick={switchToOutsideView}>Outside view</button>
   <button onClick={switchToDriverSeatView}>Inside ciew</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I rotate the camera using controls and not the object?

Comment: By `useFrame` for example... Can you provide some code, codesandbox etc?

Comment: code is here: but looks small there: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vgk7pl?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1
what I'm trying to achieve is when I click on the button it needs to change the controls and camera view to the updated one and also move to that camera position